# Chilkat SFTP file modified time not updating with uploads

Tags: c++, chilkat

I've created a service that uploads large files automatically to our server with Chilkat's SFTP. On that server, we run another service that does things with those files after they're uploaded. That service relies on the modification date to determine when an upload is finished - if it hasn't been touched in an hour, it's assumed any transfers are finished and the file is complete.

However, the last modified time doesn't change from when the file is initially created on the server - over the ~3 hours that the file is uploading, it sticks with that original time. Our previous service that uploaded files (which broke with an upgrade) didn't have this behavior, so it all worked.

It looks like PreserveDate doesn't work to address this - is there some other property that will refresh the modification date each time a block of data is uploaded? Or I guess to upload in chunks in a loop and set the remote modification manually, but that seems to be taking a lot of the convenience out of the library.

I'm using ResumeUpload, as the files are large and the connection often dropped. This function is basically just called repeatedly on a file until it's successful.

```
bool SendFileToFTP(string filePath, string destFilePath)
{
    CkSFtp sftp;
    if (sftp.UnlockComponent(SFTPUnlockCode) != true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    sftp.put_ConnectTimeoutMs(10000);
    sftp.put_IdleTimeoutMs(10000);
    if (!sftp.Connect(FTPIP, FTPPort))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!sftp.AuthenticatePw(FTPUser, FTPPass))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!sftp.InitializeSftp())
    {
        return false;
    }
    sftp.put_PreserveDate(false);
    if (!sftp.ResumeUploadFileByName(destFile.c_str(), filePath.c_str()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just upload as filename.txt.part and when the upload is complete rename it back to the original filename.txt?
Obviously, your other service needs to ignore *.part files.

Comment: Thanks Gert!  I was going to suggest the same thing.   :)